# $M$ is maximal, $P$ is prime but not maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $R$ is commutative with $1 \in R$, then each maximal ideal of $R$ is also a prime.

The reverse doesn't hold.

> For example,  $R=K[x, y], P=\langle x \rangle, M=\langle x, y\rangle$.
>
> Then it stands $$P=\langle x \rangle \subsetneq M=\langle x, y\rangle \subsetneq K[x, y]$$
> $M$ is maximal, so also prime, but $P$ is prime but not maximal.

Can you explain how we know that $M$ is maximal and that $P$ is prime but not maximal?

$$$$

**Edit:**

To show that $P$ is prime do we do the following?

We consider the homomorphism $\phi: K[x, y] \rightarrow K[y]$ with $\phi(z)=z, \forall z \in K[y]$ and $\phi(x)=0$.

We consider a polynomial $p(x, y) \in K[x, y]$.

Applying the euclidean division of the polynomial and $x$, we get:

$$p(x,y)=x \cdot g(x, y)+r(x, y)$$

$$deg_x r(x, y)<deg(x)=1 \Rightarrow deg_x r(x, y)=0 \Rightarrow r(x, y)=r(y)$$

So $p(x, y)=x \cdot g(x, y)+r(y)$.

Let $p(x, y \in ker \phi$. Then $\phi ( p(x, y))=0 \Rightarrow r(y)=0$.

So, $p(x, y)=x \cdot g(x, y)$.

So, if $p(x, y) \in ker \phi$, then $p(x, y) \in \langle x \rangle$.

So, $ker \phi \subseteq \langle x \rangle$.

$x \in \langle x \rangle$

$\phi (x)=0$

So $x \in ker \phi$.

So, $\langle x \rangle \subseteq ker \phi$.

Therefore, $ker \phi =\langle x \rangle$.

We have that $Im \phi \subseteq K[y]$.

For each $z \in K[y]$, there is an element of $K[x, y]$ that gets mapped with $\phi$ to $z$.

So $K[y] \subseteq Im \phi$.

Therefore, $Im \phi =K$.

From the theorem of isomorphism we have that $$K[x, y] /\langle x \rangle \cong K[y]$$

$K[y]$ is an integral domain, so $K[x, y] /\langle x \rangle$ is an integral domain.

Therefore, $P=\langle x \rangle$ is a prime Ideal of $K[x, y]$.

$$$$

Can you check what I've tried?

Why is $K[y]$ an integral domain? Do we have to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

A way to see this is that $K[x,y]/M \cong K$  is a field, while $K[x,y]/P \cong K[y]$ is not a field but an integral domain.

This assumes you know the criterion or definition that $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ if and only of $R/I$ is a field, and that $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$ if and only of $R/I$ is an integral domain.

Comment: I tried to prove that $P$ is a prime Ideal. I added it in the post above. Can you tell me if it is correct?

Comment: The argument seems fine. One your question if one needs to show that $K[y]$ is an integral domain. This depends. It is not hard to do in any case. The product  of two non-zero polynomials cannot be $0$ as the leading coefficient of the product is the product of the leading coefiecients (which is non-zero as $K$ is a field, and domain would suffice).

Comment: and why is $K[y]$ not a field?

Comment: For example because $y$ does not have an inverse, as the product of $y$ with any nonzero element is always of degree at least $1$.

Comment: I understand! Thanks! $$$$ If we have to show for example that the $\langle x^2-y\rangle$ is a prime Ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$, what homomorphism do we take?

Comment: In that case the homomorphism could be to $C[y]$ with $x^2 \mapsto y$ and $y  \mapsto y$.

Comment: Aha! With what do we apply the euclidean division of $p(x, y)$ in this case ?

Comment: Sorry the homomorphism I gave was not good. It should be $y \mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto x$. You can divide by $y-x^2$ consider $y$ as the variable. The rest then contains no $y$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I have also an other question: 
Show that the ideal $\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

I took $\phi: \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ with $\phi(x)=i$ and $\phi(z)=z, \forall z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. We apply the euclidean division of $p$ with $x^2+1$ and we have $p(x)=(x^2+1)g(x)+h(x)$ with $deg(h(x)) \leq 1$.

Let $p \in ker \phi$. Then $\phi(p(x))=0 \Rightarrow (\phi(x^2)+\phi(1)) \phi(g(x))+ \phi(h(x))=0 \Rightarrow \phi(h(x))=0$ 

How do we show that $h(x)=0$ ???

Comment: You have $h(x) = a x + b $ as it is of degree at most $1$, so the image is $ai + b$ which is $0$ if and only if $a=b=0$. Then $h=0$. (In general it is better to ask new questions as question-posts not in comments)